# Repository pattern in Node.js/TypeScript - the ID is set by the database

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have been trying to implement the repository pattern in Node.js and Typescript, with some success.

But I have got stuck when trying to define the create function, which should create a new row in my database table.

My interface for the repository is defined as follows:

```
export interface BookRepository {
  create(book: Book): Promise<Book | null>
}
```

Book is my domain model, which is defined as follows:

```
export type Book = {
  id: number
  name: string
  author: string
}
```

The id is created within Postgres using an auto-incrementing value, so it is not created within my code.

The problem is that when creating a new object of Book, it expects an id field.

How can I work around this problem? I do need the id within my API, so I cannot exclude it.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible approaches would be to let the compiler know that id is not a part of the argument:

```
export interface BookRepository {
  create(book: Omit<Book, 'id'>): Promise<Book | null>
}
```

This keeps the type as you designed it but lets you loosen the input contract there.